# Grabbing part of a link from a URL in R

Tags: r, string

I have parts of links pertaining to baseball players in my character vector:

```
teamplayerlinks <- c(
    "/players/i/iannech01.shtml", 
    "/players/l/lindad01.shtml",  
    "/players/c/canoro01.shtml"
)
```

I would like to isolate the letters/numbers after the 3rd `/` sign, and before the `.sthml` portion.  I want my resulting string to read:

```
desiredlinks
# [1] "iannech01" "lindad01"  "canoro01"
```

I assume this may be a job for `sub`, but I after many trials and error, I'm having a very tough time learning the escape and character sequences.  I know it can be done with two `sub` calls to remove the front and back portion, but I'd rather complete this to dynamically handle other links.

Thank you in advance to anyone who replies - I'm still learning R and trying to get better everyday.

Comment: you can try gsub(".shtml","",basename(teamplayerlinks))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
gsub(".*/|\\..*$", "", teamplayerlinks)
# [1] "iannech01" "lindad01"  "canoro01"
```

Here we have

- `.*/` remove everything up to and including the last `/`
- `|` or
- `\\..*$` remove everything after the `.`, starting from the end of the string

By the way, these look a bit like player IDs given in the Lahman baseball data sets.  If so, you can use the *Lahman* package in R and not have to scrape the web.  It has numerous baseball data sets.  It can be installed with `install.packages("Lahman")`.  I also wrote a package *retrosheet* for downloading data sets from retrosheet.com. It's also on CRAN.  Check it out!

Answer (score 2):

The `basename` function is useful here.

```
gsub("\\.shtml", "", basename(teamplayerlinks))
# [1] "iannech01" "lindad01"  "canoro01"
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be also done without regex

```
tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(teamplayerlinks))
#[1] "iannech01" "lindad01"  "canoro01"
```